# Apache Drill - MSSQL plugin error : Unknown SQL Type -155

Tags: apache-drill

I'm trying to send a query to various DBs with REST API.
So try to use Apache Drill, and I have an issue with only MSSQL query. (not in MYSQL)

Everytime send a simple test query, I got the following error:

**Error : VALIDATION ERROR : Unknown SQL type -155**

changing driver version, test query and checking configuration was useless.
Please help

```
show schema;
use dbname.schema;
show tables;
-> these are OK
select * from table limit 10;
OR 
select * from table where uid = 'something';
-> error occured (Error : VALIDATION ERROR : Unknown SQL type -155)
```

```
Plugin Configuration
{
  type: "jdbc",
  enabled: true,
  driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  url:"jdbc:sqlserver://databaseIP;databaseName=databaseName",
  username:"username",
  password:"password"
}
```

```
Error Log in sqlline.log
[Error Id: 20460622-030d-4afe-a1bc-b86834aaef3d ]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.QueryResultHandler.resultArrived(QueryResultHandler.java:123) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.handle(UserClient.java:422) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.handle(UserClient.java:96) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcBus$InboundHandler.decode(RpcBus.java:273) [drill-rpc-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcBus$InboundHandler.decode(RpcBus.java:243) [drill-rpc-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88) [netty-codec-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287) [netty-handler-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:312) [netty-codec-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286) [netty-codec-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131) [netty-common-4.0.48.Final.jar:4.0.48.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown SQL type -155
```

Referenced site : https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/

mssql driver : [sqljdbc41.4.2.6420.100.jar](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=11774)

Comment: Which data types are in your table? Maybe some specific to MSSQL?

Comment: Yes, one of table data type was datetimeoffset. I tried query other table -use datetime- was success. 
The cause of the problem was the use of data types not supported in drill.

Comment: The problem here is in Calcite's jdbc adapter which is used by Drill. I have created Jira for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-3533.